# Responsive menu from text to icon, in Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, zurb-foundation

I want to make menu tansition from text (in large for desktop) to icon (in medium and small for mobile and tablet).

Is there a way to do something like this with the tools from Foundation 5?

PS. if this opperation is posible in bootstrap, I will make the switch :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Foundation's visibility classes to show/hide specific elements on different screen sizes, like such:

```
<li>
  <a href="#" class="show-for-medium-up">Desktop Text Link</a>
  <a href="#" class="hide-for-medium-up">Mobile Icon Link</a>
</li>
```

More information on Foundation's visibility classes: http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/visibility.html